# RavenDB C# API: How to perform query filter on server side

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

I have over 128 documents in my Raven database of type `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

For two documents, the `Name` property has value `"MyName"`.

With an `IDocumentSession session`, if I perform `session.query<Foo>().Where(f => f.Name.equals("MyName"))`, I get zero results. This appears to be because the two documents that match `"MyName"` are not returned in the 128 documents returned from the RavenDB server (which is the default client-side page size). So, the client API filters by `Name=="MyName"` on the 128 documents returned, but since my two matching documents were not among those first 128, no matching documents are found. I verified this hypothesis by 1. looking at my RavenDb studio in my browser and verifying that these two documents exist, and 2. by implementing an unbounded, streaming query and successfully retrieving these two documents:

```
var results = new List<Foo>();
var query = session.Query<Foo>().Where(f => f.Name.equals("MyName");
using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query){
  while (enumerator.MoveNext()){
    results.Add(enumerator.Current.Document);
  }
}
```

However, the streaming solution is not ideal for me. My question is the following: is there a way to ask RavenDB to perform the filter on Name on the server, before returning 128 documents to the client? I want to search through all documents in my database for my given `Where` filter, but once the filter is applied, I am perfectly content to have the server return <= 128 documents to the client API.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is not correct. The default page size applies to the result of the query and not to the document collection you are querying on (if this was really true it would cause ugly problems left and right as you have no control over what comes first and what comes last in the collection).

Are you actually executing the query (i.e. calling `query.ToList()` or something similiar)? - If you do, please provide further code showing your query and assigning the result.

**EDIT**

So this here works as expected on my machine:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest3
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    public UnitTest3()
    {
        _documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            Configuration =
            {
                RunInUnreliableYetFastModeThatIsNotSuitableForProduction = true,
                RunInMemory = true,
            }
        }.Initialize();
    }

    public void InsertDummies()
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "Foo" + i };
                session.Store(foo);
            }

            Foo fooA = new Foo { Name = "MyName"};
            session.Store(fooA);
            Foo fooB = new Foo { Name = "MyName" };
            session.Store(fooB);

            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Query()
    {
        List<Foo> result;
        InsertDummies();
        using (IDocumentSession session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            result = session.Query<Foo>().Where(f => f.Name.Equals("MyName")).ToList();
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count);
    }
}
```

Did you check whether the index might be stale? - https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/stale-indexes

Comment: The method essentially returns `List<Foo>`, and I return `query.ToList()`. Thanks, I thought that couldn't be right. I'm going to play around with it a little more today and see if I can figure out why I'm seeing this behavior.